# Spring MVC :JSP form values getting bound as char array

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have an issue here.
i have table in my jsp which has a input box in every td 
my html source has the following for a

```
<input type="text" name="sessionVO.tableGroupDetails[2].colValues[0]" value="5"/>
```

when i submit the form and debug colvalues arraylist i see a char array [5] which should just be string value 5.here is my colvalues defintion.

```
private List<String> colValues;
```

below is the screenshot of my debugger.
[image]
Could anyone please help me understand what is happening?Thanks in advance

Srinivasan

Comment: The above is not a valid Java field declaration.

Comment: Sorry.My mistake.Edited

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your debugger? What happens when you execute `for (String s : colValues) {System.out.println(s);}`?

Comment: are you able to see the screnshot?

Comment: colValues is an ArrayLis containing other ArrayList instances. The first one contains just one object, but we don't know its type because you didn't expand its node. I'm not seeing any char array. Do you have several fields with the same name in your form?

Comment: no.i have checked it.there are no 2 fields with the same name.updated the screenshot.Colvalues shod be a list of string but it comes as a list of lists.what shoudl have been bound as [9,5,3,4,5] is getting bound as [9],[5],[3],[4],[5]

Comment: Your code:-

     <input type="text" name="sessionVO.tableGroupDetails[2].colValues[0]" value="5"/>

The screen shot that you have showed is :-


     sessionVO.tableGroupDetails[0].colValues

Comment: Declared String in bean but you are getting List . Definitely it is not possible behavior

Comment: @Boss: generics are only enforced at compile-time. Using reflection, or simply raw types, it's perfectly possible to store anything inside a `List<String>`.

Comment: @JB only possible in debugging or in output too..?

Comment: If you call `String s = list.get(0);` and the list contains something other than a String, you'll get a ClassCastException.

Comment: when i iterate colvalues using the for each as mentioned i get a class cast exception :(